# Pass data from one view to another in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a listbox that is filled up with JSON data. Now when I press on a item inside that listbox, I should go to detail page about that item. I have this code for my listbox.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="0,5,0,0">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="350"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding imgurl}" MaxHeight="110" MaxWidth="110" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,2,0" FontSize="20" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Now for navigating I do this in the `PhoneList_SelectionChanged`.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/NewsDetail.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

I know that I can pass values to this URI using `?value1=testtest`
But my question is now I can I pass those values to the URI?

any help?

Comment: Here's how Caliburn micro Builds a URI appending data if needed. http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9d5d0047e30e#src/Caliburn.Micro.WP71.Extensions/UriBuilder.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In selection changed event you have to know the object which you have selected. The code structure is as follows:

```
PhoneModel model = PhoneList.SelectedItem as PhoneModel;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/NewsDetail.xaml?value1="+model.title, UriKind.Relative));
```

PhoneModel is the model of items list which you are binding to the listBox. The above code snippet sends title in the navigation. You have to replace it with your requirement.

For sending more than one parameters in navigation you have to follow this pattern:

```
PhoneModel model = PhoneList.SelectedItem as PhoneModel;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/NewsDetail.xaml?value1="+model.title+"&value2="+model.imgurl, UriKind.Relative));
```