# How can push data from one page to another?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have multiple settings on one page in my project that I need to push to another page.

There are some vars, guess I could make some get variables on the navigation url, but is there a session or some kind I can use to temporary store the variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass data from one view to another in windows phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349228/pass-data-from-one-view-to-another-in-windows-phone)

Comment: or better yet, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953491/passing-data-from-page-to-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to have session like treatment is isolatedstroragesettings.

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settingss = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

To store and retrive values you need to do the following:

```
private void SaveValue()
    {
        settingss["userid"] = "IMMNK";
    }

    private string ReturnValue()
    {
        string value="";
        if (settingss.Contains("userid"))
            settingss.TryGetValue("userid", out value);
        return value;
    }
```